# cd command not working anymore

Tags: command-line, bash, cd-command

I just did two things : install [scm_breeze](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze) and mercurial :

```
git clone git://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze.git ~/.scm_breeze
~/.scm_breeze/install.sh
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

And now my cd command seems to be gone :

```
dys@dys-tour:~/prog> cd ~
bash: /home/dys : is a folder
dys@dys-tour:~/prog> cd ..
.. : command not found
```

The terminals I opened before installing scm_breeze and mercurial are fine. The terminals I open now have the problem. I uninstalled scm_breeze, with no result.

What can I do to diagnose the problem and fix it ?

Comment: What do you get from `builtin type cd`?

Comment: seems to be a bug made by scm_breeze : `cd is an alias to « exec_scmb_expand_args  »`... How can I fix that properly (please make it an answer).

Comment: Did you by any chance change your `.bashrc` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'builtin' type cd` will tell you what `cd` actually means for your current shell. It is probably aliased to something else. You can still get the original `cd` by using `'builtin' cd` or `'cd'`.

Answer (score 2):

Removing all traces of sh files installed by scm_breeze fixed the problem.

It was (I didn't found where) adding an alias to `exec_scmb_expand_args`.